# Implementing JS decorator for chaining Class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

How could I implement a decorator that makes all methods of a class automatically chainable?

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
  async foo() { console.log(1); }
  async bar() { console.log(2); }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
@chainableMethods
class MyClass {
  ...
}

const myInstance = MyClass();

myInstance
  .foo()
  .bar();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
function chainableMethods (constructor) {
  let funcs = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor.prototype);
  for (var i in funcs) {
    let func = funcs[i];
    let oldFunc = constructor.prototype[func];
    constructor.prototype[func] = (...args) => {
      let result = oldFunc.apply(this, args);
      return result || constructor.prototype;
      // Using 'result ||' for cases when a function does return something useful
      // You can remove it if it doesn't suit your requirement. 
    }
  }
}
```

If you intend on running `bar` only after the promise of `foo` is resolved then I don't think that will be possible.

Comment: I think you want result || this and you dont need the spread, just use arguments keyword.

Comment: Using the spread in case there are multiple arguments. Initially I did not have the `result ||` but added it in case there is a function which returns something useful. In such cases it's better to have an error in the system than blindly chain the events.

Comment: This doesn't work. You cannot use an arrow function to create a (prototype) method, and you should not return the prototype object for chaining.